# ASP.NET MVC Change Response Header when Serving Javascript/CSS Files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cache-control

Is there a way to automatically change the response header in ASP.NET MVC when the browser requests a Javascript or CSS file?

Basically, I want my Javascript and CSS files to be served with this set explicitly on in the response header:

```
Cache-Control: public
```

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an article you may find useful for adding Expires or Cache Control Header to static content in IIS.

Hope it helps.

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/staticContent/clientCache

Comment: +1 This helped alot. Do you know if there is any way to 'define' static content so I don't have to guess what IIS considers static content? For example if I render charts (which are sensitive from a security standpoint) I don't want those cached as 'static' images. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to http server you can make it on http layer using some rewrite mechanism - it will be fastest way. Some hardware loadbalancer also allows this.